# DB connections. SQL retrieve error

Tags: php

I define all my connections on an external file called db_config.php
This enables my class files to use db_config.php file for connections.

However, I am wondering if someone could shed some light on the following error.

```
SQL Retrieve Error: No database selected
```

This is referring to this line of code on db_config.php.

```
return array("host"=>"x", "username"=>"x", "password"=>"x", "dbname"=>"x" );
```

This is the function that makes the call

```
function openDB() {
    $config = include_once("assets/configs/db_config.php");
    $conn = mysqli_connect(
        $config["host"] , $config["username"],
        $config["password"], $config["dbname"]);
    $this->conn = $conn;
    return true;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure the value of `$config["dbname"]` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Do a dump on your `$config` variable to check if the values are being passed correctly

Comment: @Orangepill All correct. Any other suggestions, please?

Comment: Instead of  `$config = include_once("assets/configs/db_config.php");` try  `$config = include_once "assets/configs/db_config.php";`

Comment: @GnikcufSullBhit Try changing include_once to include, if you are including it prior to this point you are going to be getting  null instead of an array.

Comment: Why are people answering in the comments instead of the Answer box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure the variables in the config file are correct. If they are correct the try changing the include_once to include.

if that is not working, then change the code to :

```
function openDB() {
    $config = array("host"=>"x", "username"=>"x", "password"=>"x", "dbname"=>"x" );
    $conn = mysqli_connect(
        $config["host"] , $config["username"],
        $config["password"], $config["dbname"]);
    $this->conn = $conn;
    return true;
}
```

See if this works my way. If it does then your won't need the db.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Please dump the $config variable and check what is going wrong ,

```
     <?php
     var_dump($config); 
     ?>
```

So you can find $config is returning an array or not !